# Ruby: why does =~ evaluate to true in an if statement?

Tags: ruby, regex, if-statement, pattern-matching, string-matching

I'm learning Ruby and have seen (and using) regex matching in this way:

```
a = "string9"
if a =~ /\d/
  #do something
end
```

The code would work but today I read the documentation on Regex and learned that =~ returns the position of the match in the string, nil if no match. I thought =~ returns true or false when it is the === that returns true for match, and false for no match. It seems the if statement in the above code should be rewritten:

```
if /\d/ === a
```

I have tried both and the program would run without error. I'm just trying to understand what's going on. It seems "if" will take anything but "nil" as true. I guess my question is less about regex but more about how the if statement (and other boolean statements) works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicate after `if` will be treated as a boolean value.

In Ruby, only `false` and `nil` are treated as `false`. Anything other will be evaluated to `true`, so `0`, `[]`, `{}` are all `true` in boolean context.

From [Ruby doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Booleans+and+nil):

> nil and false are both false values. nil is sometimes used to indicate "no value" or "unknown" but evaluates to false in conditional expressions.
>
> true is a true value. All objects except nil and false evaluate to a true value in conditional expressions.

And you may have a look at [the control expressions](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html).

Comment: thank you, i knew i must have missed a documentation somewhere. Couldn't find it for some reason. Thanks for the link.